# VS Code debugger: Rebuild if source file is newer than module file

Tags: visual-studio-code

If I attempt to debug with a newer source file, I get a warning in the console:

`Warning: Source file 'foo.c' is newer than module file 'foo'.`

It would be nice if I had an option to always force a build when running the debugger.

Is there a way to chain `launch.json`'s configuration with tasks, similar to `tasks.json`'s `dependsOn` attribute?

Comment: launch.json does have a way to always build when running. Try adding the following to run the build task before launching:  "preLaunchTask": "build",

Comment: @alexriedl D'oh! Submit an answer and claim your prize.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The launch.json has an optional preLaunchTask configuration. Set the value of this configuration to the name of the task you want to run before launching. For example add the following to your launch configuration:

```
"preLaunchTask": "build",
```

This will run the "build" task before launching.

For more information about available configuration in the launch.json file look at the vscode [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging) page.